# Assembly decoder with jmp-pop-call technique

Tags: python, assembly

This is a part of code in which I cannot figure out the mistake. I am using the jmp-pop-call technique and what I get is "Segmentation Fault". Tried to use GDB but things are really vague. Each byte is encoded by 1 in python and what I want is to decode with the following part of code:

global _start
section .text

_start:

```
jmp short call_shellcode
```

decoder:

```
pop esi
xor eax, eax
mov edx, 23
```

decode:

```
mov bl, byte[esi+eax]
dec byte[esi+eax]
```

cont:

```
cmp eax,edx
jz short encodedShellcode
inc eax
jmp short decode
```

call_shellcode:

```
call decoder
encodedShellcode db 0x32,0xc1,0x51,0x69,0x30,0x74,0x69,0x69,0x30,0x63,0x6a,0x6f,0x8a,0xe4,0x51,0x54,0x8a,0xe2,0x9a,0xb1,0x0c,0xce,0x81,
```

Comment: You need to show more of the code.  What you have posted here doesn't make sense on its own.  For example, your decoder pops into ESI but there's never a push anywhere in what you've posted.  We also can't see where the ES/DS are initialized which are possible sources of your segmentation fault since this indicates that you are attempting to read memory that you don't own.

Comment: I answered your identical question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557175/assembly-decoder-with-jmp-pop-call-technique